# iphone JS swipe action to load next page

Tags: jquery, iphone, ipad, jqtouch

I hace been looking around on how to make a swipe action with javascript so that it loads $next (the next page). Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Sam Shull's](http://samshull.blogspot.com/2010/06/jqtouch-photo-gallery.html) [photo gallery](http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/source/browse/jqt.photo.js) [extension](http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions) for some techniques in doing this.